# How to port a pre 1.13 plugin to 1.15 or higher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-spigot

I want to try and port an open source plugin to 1.15, I have experience coding plugins and with Java etc. But none porting any advice for the best way to go about porting plugins?

Comment: Hi 1poo, sorry but plugin development is off-topic on Arqade. Generally, game plugin questions might fit better on [gamedev.se].

Answer (score 2):

Start with importing the project into your IDE.
The next step is to add the newer version of the API to your project's build path. If the project is using Maven or Gradle, the API should be listed as a dependency in your pom.xml (for Maven) or build.gradle (for Gradle) and you can change the version by editing those files. If the project doesn't use Maven or Gradle, you will have to add the API manually. How you do that depends on which IDE you are using so Google it.

After you've added the API to your project's build path, your IDE should display errors if the plugin is using parts of the API that changed between those versions. Fix the errors if there are any and test the plugin. From here, it's basically just testing the plugin and fixing anything that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for this:

- Find out what changes break it
- Fix the code so it don't crash anymore.

No Faster and Easier way than find out what changed in the time between 1.13 and 1.15 which makes the Plugin not runable anymore and fix them